# How to upload Chirp audio file into Google Cloud and make media URN using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, chirp

I need to make text encryption via chirp. After that encryption audio file should upload into Google Cloud and make media URL using Nodejs

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. As I understand you want to encrypt a text, then upload an audio file into google cloud (storage maybe?, you should specify) and then get a media URL (like the url that Cloud Storage generates for each object?) What is the relation between the text encrypted and the media thingy?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than uploading the Chirp audio data to Google Cloud, you can generate audio on the fly using the Audio API - https://developers.chirp.io/docs/getting-started/audio-api.

So you would need to encrypt your data using something like AES, and convert this to a hexadecimal string to be consumed by the Audio API.